# Update doesn't work as should be in MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

```
 echo $totalprice;
echo "<br/>";
echo $shortfall;
echo "<br/>";
echo $unitprice;
echo "<br/>";
```

I got

> 24 80
>   0.3

Then the following command was executed.

// update query

However, only

> total_price

was changed(became 0.00) while other values like

> unit_price

stay unchanged. But other values like

> unit_price

should be changed.

> Total_price

is

> unsigned
>   when total_price-pricebalance is done, it becomes 0.00.
>   So does it refuse to subtract $totalprice?
>   Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the actual mysql query that was executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `AND`s in your UPDATE query?

```
mysql_query("update piecework set total_price=total_price-pricebalance+$totalprice, quota=quota-shortfall+$shortfall, shortfall=$shortfall, unit_price=$unitprice, pricebalance=$totalprice where piecework_id='$pieceworkid' and publisher=$memberid and (pricebalance-$totalprice)>=0")or die(mysql_error());
```

Or with better readability:

```
UPDATE piecework SET total_price = total_price - pricebalance + $totalprice,
                     quota = quota - shortfall + $shortfall,
                     shortfall = $shortfall,
                     unit_price = $unitprice,
                     pricebalance = $totalprice
...
```